# Floor-Based Electrical outlet type

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Is there any requirement that mandates a residential floor-installed electrical receptacle to be a GFCI type, when said location is in a dining area, NOT located in the bathroom, kitchen, laundry / NOT near water source? Thank you!

Comment: GFCI *receptacles* are never, ever required.  Never.  Where GFCI *protection* is required, you are allowed to use a variety of methods to provide it, such as downstream feeding, deadfront, GFCI breaker, whole subpanel GFCI, you name it.

Comment: Great, Appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3):

### No, this receptacle doesn't have to be GFCI protected

The primary clause that requires GFCI protection in residential kitchens only applies to kitchen *countertop* receptacles (there's also a GFCI requirement for dishwashers, but that's a different thing):

> (6) Kitchens — where the receptacles are installed to serve
>   the countertop surfaces

### However, it does need to be *installed correctly*

The problem with a receptacle in the floor, though, is that putting a regular box and receptacle in the floor yields a *hazardous* installation (due to crud getting into the receptacle), and is prohibited by 314.27(B), which requires a listed floor box and matching faceplate be used instead:

> **(B) Floor Boxes.** Boxes listed specifically for this application
>   shall be used for receptacles located in the floor.

So, you need to make sure the box is listed and labeled as a *floor box* -- these will generally have a distinctive faceplate that has flip-open covers over the receptacles themselves.